# why is list[-1:1] empty in python?

Tags: python, list

```
>>>list=[1,2,3]  
>>>list[1:2]  
2  
>>>list[-1:1]  
[]
```

In python, `list[first:last]` is `return list[first,first+1,...last-1]`
but `list[-1:1]` is return empty, why not include `list[-1]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What are you expecting to return? Your `-1` position in that list is `2`, so your `list[-1:1]` is the same as `list[2:1]` which is empty list. You could do it with `step=-1`:

```
list[-1:1:-1]
3
```

*Note*: Usually it's not a good idea to reassign built-in variables such as `list`. It's better to use some othe name, i.e. `l`:

```
l = [1,2,3]

l[1]
2

l[-1]
3

l[-1:1]
[]

l[-1:1:-1]
[3]
```

Comment: "usually" is an understatement :D

Answer (score 0):

in `list[first,last]`... the order matters

`list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

if we try `list[4,2]`
first = 4
and last = 2...(error..!!!!!)
it returns `[]`

u can use

```
>>> list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list[::-1]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```